# How to comment in Vim's config files: ".vimrc"?

Tags: vim, comments, configuration-files

How do I add a comment in Vim's configuration files, like `.vimrc?`

Answer (score 616, accepted):

A double quote to the left of the text you want to comment.

Example:
`"   this is how a comment looks like in ~/.vimrc`

To be clear: Do not include a closing double quote.  (See comment from Arslan Ali below.)

Comment: And it shouldn't have a closing `"`.

Comment: And it shouldn't be an inline comment, for inline (better: at-the-end-of-line comments) you can use `command foo |" my comment`    (pipe for command separaion needed)

Comment: I had modelines enabled (they let you define variables in header/footer of files), with a first line in `.vimrc` that was:
`" Configuration file for vim: some useful features`

When opening `.vimrc` with vim, I would get the error message:
```Error detected while processing modelines```

I ended up disabling modelines with `set nomodeline`. 

The issue is specific to that first comment in the file, the position of the `:` or some other keyword. I haven't located it precisely.

Answer (score 145):

```
"This is a comment in vimrc. It does not have a closing quote
```

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backing_up_and_commenting_vimrc

Comment: add a pipe before the double qoute if there is a command on the left of the comment

Answer (score 16):

Same as above. Use double quote to start the comment and without the closing quote.

Also, you can have **command followed by comment** in file .vimrc just like below:

```
set nu  "display line number
```

Comment: No need to repeat

Answer (score 14):

You can add comments in Vim's configuration file by either:

```
" brief description of the command
```

or:

```
"" commented command
```

Taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690040/vimrc-file-comments-double-quotes-vs-two-double-quotes)